# Pandas: check if a value in a tuple by using in keyword

Tags: python, tuples

When I write:

```
fruit=("mango","apple")

"m" in fruit
```

the output is "false"

But when I write:

```
fruit=("mango","apple")

"m" in fruit[0]
```

the output is "True"

Could someone please explain this to me? I am new to programming, this seems confusing to me :(

Comment: That's because a tuple contains multiple elements. You are trying to access a letter in the element of a tuple, which in your case is a string. You need to access the index of the tuple elements. `fruit[0] -> 'mango'`, therefore `'m' in 'mango' -> True`.

Comment: Similarly, `[1, 2] in [[1, 2], [3, 4]]` but `1 not in [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

Comment: better check python fundamental tutorials, tuple, array, string section

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `in` checks for presence in the direct sublevel (unless using a custom object with a modified `__contains__` method).

`fruit` contains two objects, the string `"mango"` and the string `"apple"`. Thus only `"apple" in fruit` and `"mango" in fruit` will return `True`.

When you run `"m" in fruit[0]` you actually test `"m" in "mango"`, which is `True` as `"mango"` is an *iterable* (a string is an immutable container of individual characters, similar to a list but which cannot be modified), and the character `"m"` is contained in it.

If you want to test for the presence of a character/substring in any of the strings of the tuple `fruit` you can use:

```
any("m" in item for item in fruit)
```

Output: `True`